# Tex compilation after regex replace

Tags: expl3, l3regex

I need to produce a variable-sized string consisting of even number of Latin letters, each pair being of the format `a\textrightarrow A;`. Each pair separated from the other pairs by some empty space (here 1cm for example). For this I define a command `\midarrow` and use `\regex_replace` of `expl3` to modify the argument of `\midarrow`.

I want `\midarrow` to convert

1. "a,A;b,B;c,C" to "(a->A); (b->B); (c->C)"
2. "a,A;b,B;c,C;d,D" to "(a->A); (b->B); (c->C); (d->D)"
3. "->" above should be actual arrows produced by `\textrightarrow`

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\midarrow}{m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { (#1) }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { , } { \textrightarrow } \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ; } { );\hspace{1cm}( } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \midarrow{a,A;b,B;c,C}
\end{document}
```

However I get garbage as result. How do I make sure that the result of `\regex_replace_all` should be compiled by pdfLaTeX and produce the desired output?

PS: I am not proficient in latex3. I have just reused and modified code I found on this site to suit my purposes.

Comment: You could simply use `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { , } { \textrightarrow }` and `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ; } { );\hspace{1cm}( }` instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should follow special rules in the replacement text:

- Use `\c{cmd}` to represent control sequence `\cmd`.
- Use `\cB\{` and `\cE\}` to represent **b**egin and **e**nd group brace, respectively.
- To ensure the category codes, escape every printable character other than `a-zA-Z0-9`. For example, use `\(` to represent character `(`, and use `(...)` to represent a capturing group. (Thanks for @frougon's comment.)

Therefore your example can be modified to be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\midarrow}{m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { (#1) }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \, } { \c{textrightarrow} } \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \; } { \)\; \c{hspace}\cB\{ 1cm \cE\} \( } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \midarrow{a,A;b,B;c,C}
\end{document}
```

Use the [document `interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), part XXVII as a thorough introduction to `l3regex` library.

Comment: Thanks! That works very well. However I am curious as to what should I do if I wanted to use ```$\rightarrow$ ``` instead of ```\textrightarrow```?

Comment: You can use `\cM$ \c{rightarrow} \cM$`. The parentheses and semicolon (`;`) should be preceded by a ``\`` because the manual says (p. 223 here) “non-alphanumeric printable ascii characters can (and should) always be escaped: many of them have special meanings (e.g., use `\(`, `\)`, `\?`, `\.`)”, where *alphanumeric* has been defined as `A–Z`, `a–z`, `0–9`. You should read the `l3regex` chapter in the link muzimuzhi Z gave you.

Comment: @frougon Thanks for pointing out that. Answer updated.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't use `\regex_replace:nnN` for this job.

My suggestion is to split the input at the semicolons; then apply to each item a command for the arrow and finally use the sequence with the desired space between items.

The arrow making function uses the fact that you have two items separated by a comma, so it's good input for a `clist`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\midarrow}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_magguu_arrows_in_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_magguu_arrows_out_seq \l_magguu_arrows_in_seq
   { \magguu_arrows_make:n { ##1 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_magguu_arrows_out_seq { \hspace{1cm} }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \magguu_arrows_make:n
 {
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 }
  \textrightarrow
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\midarrow{a,A;b,B;c,C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is immaterial if you input `\midarrow{a,A;b,B;c,C}` or

```latex
\midarrow{
  a, A;
  b, B;
  c, C
}
```